# Текст, занимающий часть пространства, выравненный слева, должен оказаться справа

Tags: текст, latex, выравнивание

Я оформляю исследовательскую работу для конкретного конкурса. В технических требованиях прикреплён [шаблон](https://www.hse.ru/mirror/pubs/share/854082636.pdf), в приложении можно найти образец титульного листа работы.
[image: образец титульного листа]

Текст про автора выравнен слева, но прикреплён в правой границе текста. Как это реализовать?

Про выравнивание текста говорят только в [строке](https://ru.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Text_alignment) (текст будет прикреплён к той стороне, с которой выравнен). Есть [такие решения](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55472/how-to-make-text-aligned-left-center-right-in-the-same-line), но опять не решают мою "двухмерную" проблему. Моё использует `flushleft` и `flushright` внутри, но это не работает (на текст внутри применяется только последний `flush<сторона>{}`).

Comment: А Вы бы не могли сюда выложить Вашу попытку создать титульный лист, чтобы я (или кто-то еще) его мог просто немного подправить, а не создавать с нуля :-)? Там все довольно просто. (ну и самому создавать чужой текст с нуля мне скучно, да и правилами ресурса предполагается, что Вы должны приложить хотя бы попытку сделать как хочется).